# JQuery height does not return exact height

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I have a problem I don't understand and googling hasn't been of much help either, I want to get height of a div with a p tag in multiple lines as of the image
[image: div image]

The height returned is as if the p tag is in only one line but after it has already rendered and spans over the multiple lines, when you call the function height it displays the actual results, how do I actually get it to display the actual height from my javascript code?
What I have so far is

```
console.log($('div.content-wrapper').height(), $('div.content-wrapper').outerHeight())
```

which both display same thing.

```
Height displayed: 42
Actual height: 86
```

P.S. I am creating the element from JS

```
$('div.container').append(' \
  <div class="content-wrapper"> \
    <p class="text"></p> \
    <div class="button"> \
      <span class="button-text"></span> \
    </div> \
  </div> \
');
```

Comment: Please put your height measure code inside document.ready and just before end of that.

Comment: And add the accompanying html please

Answer (score 1):

```
$(element).outerHeight()
```

will return height including height with borders and paddings

use,

```
$(element).outerHeight(true)
```

to include margins as well.

Also, if you have many other elements in your wrapper DIV tag than you can use below code.

```
$(window).load(function(){  
   $("wrapper-element").children().each(function(){
     totalHeight = totalHeight + $(this).outerHeight(true);
   });
});
```

Comment: *element in first line :)

Comment: that doesn't work, did I mention I am creating the DOM element from Js

Comment: When exactly you append you wrapper in DOM? On click, after page is loaded or something else?

Comment: actually its a function which can be called from anytime, but in this case i am calling the function inside a document.ready @JoshulSharma

Comment: nop, @JoshulSharma there is only two element and one of them has position display,  so the other matters most

Comment: ok, then try to use children loop in $(window).load(function(){  #code...});....Also keep in mind that loop is counting height(margin,padding...etc) of elements inside the wrapper element.